Gravity Froms API Version 2 form submission issue
I created a custom form on elementor and now want to use gravity forms as a backend so I wrote an ajax request to send the data to gravity forms, the issue is that the fields are not being mapped for some reason. I looked into the documentation and it says that it maps using the field ID but I'm not sure what it refers to is it the name attribute or the ID attribute? Can anyone clarify this.
const formID = 15;

// Gather form data
const formData = {
  input_1: document.getElementById("name").value,
  input_2: document.getElementById("phone").value,
  input_3: document.getElementById("email").value,
};
console.log(formData);

// AJAX request to submit data
$.ajax({
  url: "/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/" + formID + "/submissions",
  method: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    input_values: formData,
  }),
  contentType: "application/json",
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    // You may need to send an authentication header
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("key1:Key2"));
  },
  success: function (response) {
    console.log("Form submitted successfully:", response);
    alert("Form submission successful!");
  },
  error: function (error) {
    console.error("Error submitting the form:", error);
    console.log(data);
    alert("There was an error submitting the form.");
  },
});

I tried changing the mapping to ID and Name attribute but no luck, do I have to enable any setting from wordpress? I have already enabled the API version 2 from the GravityForms admin but it still does not work.

Can you share your PHP codes too?

you mean the form?

Uh, I just realized that you shouldn't have custom PHP codes in the backend for this, do you see any error in your browser's console? also can you share the result of console.log(formData)?

I figured out the issue, basically i was wrapping the formData in another object by mistake,
data: JSON.stringify({
input_values: formData
}),
is wrong, I just fixed this and it worked:
data: JSON.stringify(
formData
),
thanks for the help though!

I was wrapping the formData in another object by mistake,
data: JSON.stringify({ input_values: formData })

This is wrong. I fixed this and it worked:
data: JSON.stringify( formData )

